# Default value on generic predicate as argument

Tags: c#, arguments, default-value, predicate

First time question for me :)

I need some way to define a default predicate using a generic on the format

```
Func<T, bool>
```

and then use this as a default argument. Something like this:

```
public bool Broadcast(byte command, MemoryStream data, bool async, Func<T, bool> predicate = (T t) => true)
```

When i do this i get the compile error:

Default parameter value for 'predicate' must be a compile-time constant

Is there a smooth way of doing this that I am missing or should a make the predicate function nullable and change my function logic accordingly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Default values for method parameters have to be compile-time constants, as the default values are actually copied to all the call sites of the method by the compiler.

You have to use an overload to do this:

```
public bool Broadcast(byte command, MemoryStream data, bool async) {
    return Broadcast(command, data, async, t => true);
}

public bool Broadcast(byte command, MemoryStream data, bool async, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
    // ...
}
```

Also, there is a specific `Predicate<T>` delegate in mscorlib which you can use instead. It's the same signature as `Func<T, bool>`, but it explicitly marks it as a delegate which decides whether an action is performed on instances of `T`

Comment: I´m going with this for the extra information provided about the Predicate<T>

Answer (score 3):

Make an overload for Broadcast which does not take the last argument.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public bool Broadcast(byte command, MemoryStream data, bool async, Func<T, bool> predicate = default(Func<T, bool>))
```

But I think you have to check for predicate!=null.

Comment: In this case i might as well just do public bool Broadcast(byte command, MemoryStream data, bool async, Func<T, bool> predicate = null)